# Is there any alternative for JSON_VALUE in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, json-value

Is there any alternative for JSON_VALUE in SQL Server 2014?
JSON_VALUE is supported SQL Server 2016 and higher. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I have seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732623/json-value-for-sql-server-2012) the problem, and I need this too.
So I wrote a function which JSON_VALUE alternative for pre-SQL Server 2016. You can check this [github](https://github.com/yalcinmuhammed/GET_JSON_VALUE/blob/main/GET_JSON_VALUE).
I hope it helps someone else.
Also here is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [<schema>].[GET_JSON_VALUE](@expression nvarchar(max), @path varchar(500))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
     @key varchar(100)
    ,@tempExpression nvarchar(max)
    ,@index int = NULL
    ,@keyJson varchar(100)
    ,@keyIdx int
    ,@valueIdx int
    ,@termIdx int
    ,@colonx int
    ,@quotesx int
    ,@endQuotesx int
    ,@commax int
    ,@squareBracketLeftx int = 0
    ,@tempSquareBracketLeftx int = 0
    ,@squareBracketRightx int = 0
    ,@curlyBraceLeftx int = 0
    ,@tempCurlyBraceLeftx int = 0
    ,@curlyBraceRightx int = 0
    ,@isString bit
    ,@isArray bit = 0
    IF @path is null OR @path = '' RETURN @expression

    DECLARE @dotKeyx int= CHARINDEX('.', @path)
    IF @dotKeyx <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @key = SUBSTRING(@path, 0, @dotKeyx)
        SET @path = SUBSTRING(@path, @dotKeyx+1, LEN(@path) )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @key = @path
        SET @path = null
    END
    DECLARE @squareBracketKeyx int = CHARINDEX('[', @key)
    IF @squareBracketKeyx <> 0 AND CHARINDEX(']', @key) = LEN(@key)
    BEGIN
        SET @index = SUBSTRING(@key, @squareBracketKeyx+1, LEN(@key)-@squareBracketKeyx-1)
        SET @key = SUBSTRING(@key, 0, @squareBracketKeyx)
        SET @isArray = 1;
    END
        
    SET @keyJson = '"' + @key+ '"'

    SET @tempExpression = @expression
    --find arrays and remove for searching main key
    SET @tempExpression = RIGHT(@tempExpression, LEN(@tempExpression) - 1)
    SET @tempExpression = LEFT(@tempExpression, LEN(@tempExpression) - 1)
    
    WHILE CHARINDEX('[', @tempExpression, 0) <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @squareBracketLeftx = CHARINDEX('[', @tempExpression, 0)
        SET @squareBracketRightx = CHARINDEX(']', @tempExpression, @squareBracketLeftx)
        SET @tempSquareBracketLeftx = CHARINDEX('[', @tempExpression, @squareBracketLeftx + 1)
        WHILE @tempSquareBracketLeftx <> 0 AND @tempSquareBracketLeftx < @squareBracketRightx
        BEGIN
            SET @tempSquareBracketLeftx = CHARINDEX('[', @tempExpression, @tempSquareBracketLeftx + 1)
            SET @squareBracketRightx = CHARINDEX(']', @tempExpression, @squareBracketRightx+1)
        END
        SET @tempExpression = REPLACE(@tempExpression, SUBSTRING(@tempExpression, @squareBracketLeftx, @squareBracketRightx - @squareBracketLeftx + 1), '')
    END
    
    --find objects and remove for searching main key
    WHILE CHARINDEX('{', @tempExpression, 0) <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @curlyBraceLeftx = CHARINDEX('{', @tempExpression, 0)
        SET @curlyBraceRightx = CHARINDEX('}', @tempExpression, @curlyBraceLeftx)
        SET @tempCurlyBraceLeftx = CHARINDEX('{', @tempExpression, @curlyBraceLeftx + 1)
        WHILE @tempCurlyBraceLeftx <> 0 AND @tempCurlyBraceLeftx < @curlyBraceRightx
        BEGIN
            SET @tempCurlyBraceLeftx = CHARINDEX('{', @tempExpression, @tempCurlyBraceLeftx + 1)
            SET @curlyBraceRightx = CHARINDEX('}', @tempExpression, @curlyBraceRightx+1)
        END
        SET @tempExpression = REPLACE(@tempExpression, SUBSTRING(@tempExpression, @curlyBraceLeftx, @curlyBraceRightx - @curlyBraceLeftx + 1), '')
    END
    
    --Is Exist Key
    SET @keyIdx = CHARINDEX(@keyJson, @tempExpression)
    IF @keyIdx = 0 RETURN NULL
    
    SET @keyIdx = CHARINDEX(@keyJson, @expression)
    SET @valueIdx = @keyIdx + LEN(@keyJson)

    SET @colonx = CHARINDEX(':', @expression, @valueIdx)
    SET @commax = CHARINDEX(',', @expression, @valueIdx)
    SET @quotesx = CHARINDEX('"', @expression, @valueIdx)
    SET @squareBracketLeftx = CHARINDEX('[', @expression, @valueIdx)
    SET @curlyBraceLeftx = CHARINDEX('{', @expression, @valueIdx)
    
    IF @squareBracketLeftx BETWEEN @colonx AND @quotesx --Array Content
    BEGIN
        SET @squareBracketRightx = CHARINDEX(']', @expression, @squareBracketLeftx)
        SET @tempSquareBracketLeftx = CHARINDEX('[', @expression, @squareBracketLeftx + 1)
        
        WHILE @tempSquareBracketLeftx <> 0 AND @tempSquareBracketLeftx < @squareBracketRightx
        BEGIN
            
            SET @tempSquareBracketLeftx = CHARINDEX('[', @expression, @tempSquareBracketLeftx + 1)
            SET @squareBracketRightx = CHARINDEX(']', @expression, @squareBracketRightx+1)
        END
        
        SET @expression = SUBSTRING(@expression, @squareBracketLeftx, @squareBracketRightx - @squareBracketLeftx + 1)
        
        IF @index is NULL AND (@path is null OR @path = '') RETURN @expression
        IF @index is NULL RETURN NULL

        DECLARE @i int = 0, @startCurlyBracex int = 0, @endCurlyBracex int = 0, @tempStartCurlyBracex int = 0, @indexedExpression nvarchar(max);
        WHILE @i <= @index
        BEGIN
            SET @startCurlyBracex = CHARINDEX('{', @expression, @endCurlyBracex+1)
            IF @startCurlyBracex = 0 RETURN NULL -- array out of range
            SET @endCurlyBracex = CHARINDEX('}', @expression, @startCurlyBracex)

            SET @tempStartCurlyBracex = CHARINDEX('{', @expression, @startCurlyBracex + 1)
            WHILE @tempStartCurlyBracex <> 0 AND @tempStartCurlyBracex < @endCurlyBracex
            BEGIN
                SET @tempStartCurlyBracex = CHARINDEX('{', @expression, @tempStartCurlyBracex + 1)
                SET @endCurlyBracex = CHARINDEX('}', @expression, @endCurlyBracex+1)
            END
            
            SET @indexedExpression = SUBSTRING(@expression, @startCurlyBracex, @endCurlyBracex - @startCurlyBracex + 1)
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
        
        --Call Recursive @expression, @path
        RETURN [COR].[GET_JSON_VALUE](@indexedExpression, @path)
    END
    ELSE IF @curlyBraceLeftx BETWEEN @colonx AND @quotesx --Object Content
    BEGIN
        IF @isArray = 1 RETURN NULL --It is not an object If it is array

        SET @curlyBraceRightx = CHARINDEX('}', @expression, @curlyBraceLeftx)
        SET @tempCurlyBraceLeftx = CHARINDEX('{', @expression, @curlyBraceLeftx + 1)
        WHILE @tempCurlyBraceLeftx <> 0 AND @tempCurlyBraceLeftx < @curlyBraceRightx
        BEGIN
        
            SET @tempCurlyBraceLeftx = CHARINDEX('{', @expression, @tempCurlyBraceLeftx + 1)
            SET @curlyBraceRightx = CHARINDEX('}', @expression, @curlyBraceRightx+1)
        END
        SET @expression = SUBSTRING(@expression, @curlyBraceLeftx, @curlyBraceRightx - @curlyBraceLeftx + 1)

        --Call Recursive @expression, @path
        RETURN [COR].[GET_JSON_VALUE](@expression, @path)
    END
    ELSE --Value Content
    BEGIN
        SET @termIdx = @quotesx
        IF @termIdx <> 0 
        BEGIN
            
            IF @commax = 0 SET @commax = CHARINDEX('}', @expression, @valueIdx)--end of json string
            SET @isString = 0
            --2 quatos
            SET @endQuotesx = CHARINDEX('"', @expression, @quotesx+1)--getting next quotes
            -- Overcome JSON qoute escape
            WHILE SUBSTRING(@expression, @endQuotesx-1, 1) = '\'
            BEGIN
                SET @endQuotesx = CHARINDEX('"', @expression, @endQuotesx + 1)
            END

            IF (@quotesx BETWEEN @colonx AND @commax) AND (@endQuotesx BETWEEN @colonx AND @commax)
            BEGIN
                SET @isString = 1
                SET @termIdx = @endQuotesx      -- end index
                SET @valueIdx = @quotesx + 1    -- start index
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @isString = 0
                -- Overcome spaces after comma
                WHILE SUBSTRING(@expression, @endQuotesx, 1) <> ','
                BEGIN
                    SET @endQuotesx = @endQuotesx - 1
                END
                SET @termIdx = @endQuotesx  -- end index
                SET @valueIdx = @colonx + 1 -- start index
            END
        END 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN -- end of json non-string
            SET @termIdx = CHARINDEX(',', @expression, @colonx)
            IF @termIdx = 0 SET @termIdx = CHARINDEX('}', @expression, @colonx)
            SET @valueIdx = @colonx + 1 
            SET @isString = 0
        END

        IF @termIdx = 0 RETURN NULL
        
        -- Replace escapte quote before return value
        IF @isString = 0
            RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@expression, @valueIdx, @termIdx - @valueIdx), '\"', '"')))
        ELSE
            RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@expression, @valueIdx, @termIdx - @valueIdx), '\"', '"')
    END

    RETURN NULL--Default
END
```

Comment: Honestly, this would be awfully slow. It has multiple nested `WHILE` loops. If you're on SQL Server 2014, or earlier, then you are better off consuming the values outside of SQL Server, or using CLR objects.